# How to programmatically reference a Grid that's in a ControlTemplate in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have the following ControlTemplate which contains a Grid:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SlideViewControlTemplate">
            <Grid x:Key="GridSlideViewIndicators" Padding="0,0,0,0">
                <ContentPresenter />

            </Grid>     
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

How can I refer to the Grid (GridSlideViewIndicators) in my code? I tried the following:

```
var gridSlideViewIdicators = Resources.Single(r => r.Key.Contains("GridSlideViewIndicators"));
```

But this only returns a key/value pair, not the actual Grid object.

I also tried giving the Grid a name in the XAML, but it wasn't visible to the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access the grid directly inside the ControlTemplate you need to create content first , this should work.

```
ControlTemplate x = (ControlTemplate) Resources["SlideViewControlTemplate"];
var gridSlideViewIdicators = x.CreateContent();
```